# Number of elements of a splitting field

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $\alpha$ a root of $X^3+X^2+1 \in \mathbb{F}_2[X]$ and $K=\mathbb{F}_2(\alpha)$.
Suppose $f$ is an irreducible polynomial in $K[X]$ of degree 4. Let $\beta$ be a root of $f$, and $L$ a splitting field of $f$ over $K$. What is the number of elements of $L$?

I would say, $f$ is irreducible, so $deg(\beta) = 4$. Is this claim correct?

If it is, $[L:K] = deg(\beta) = 4$, so $L$ has $8^4 = 4096$ elements? (since $K$ has 8 elements).
Is this correct reasoning?

Furthermore, how many intermediate fields does the extension $L/K$ have?

I would say 2, a field with $8^2= 64$ elements and a field with $8^3 = 512$ elements. But this is intuitively and I don't know how to prove this?

Comment: There is a mix-up there with the names of the roots. If should be $deg(\beta)=4$. You know that $[K:\mathbb{F}_2]=deg(\alpha)=3$. Now $[L:K]=4$. It can't be $2$ because otherwise $\beta$ would be a root of a polynomial of degree $2$ over $K$ and $f$ would not be irreducible. Therefore, $[L:\mathbb{F}_2]=[L:K][K:\mathbb{F}_2]=12$. Therefore, each element of $L$ can be written as a unique $\mathbb{F}_2$-linear combination of $12$ elements of $L$. Since $|\mathbb{F}_2|=2$, we have $2^{12}=8^4$ elements. To count the intermediate extensions: $[L:K]=4$. A group of order $4$ always has an element...

Comment: ... of order $2$. This forms a subgroup of order $2$. Therefore, we have $K:K$, and extension of order $2$ formed by the elements of $L$ fixed by that element of order two of $Aut(L:K)$, and $L:K$.

Comment: thank you, I edited the mix up in names of the roots

Comment: Another question, why are all roots of $f$ of the form $\beta^k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: They don't have to be. If you are talking about the argument why $[L:K]\neq 2$. In more detail it is: If that dimension is $2$, that means that $1,\beta,\beta^2$ should be linearly dependent over $K$. Therefore there are $a_0,a_1,a_2\in K$ such that $p(\beta)=a_0+a_1\beta+a_2\beta^2=0$. It follows that $\beta$ is a root of $gcd(f,p)\in K[X]$. This implies that $f$ is not irreducible, which is your contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{HINT}$$
Because of $g(x)=x^3+x^2+1\ne0$
for the only two elements of $\mathbb F_2$, the cubic $g$ is irreducible over $\mathbb F_2$ and, since $\alpha^3=\alpha^2+1$ (obviously$1=-1$ ), each element of  $\mathbb F_2(\alpha)$ has the form 
$$x=a_0+a_1\alpha+a_2\alpha^2$$ It follows that $\mathbb F_2(\alpha)$ has $2\cdot2\cdot2=8$ elements (in general all finite extension of degree $n$ de $\mathbb F_p$ has $p^n$ elements).

Now you have $$f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^4\space\text {with } f(\beta)\ne0$$ where each coefficient $a_i$ can take eight distinct values. Therefore the extension $K(\beta)$, like above, has $8\cdot8\cdot8\cdot8=2^{12}$ elements.
This is not the end because $K(\beta)$ is not the required splitting field. **Can you finish the answer guided by lines above?**

Comment: I think the point you are trying to make is, $f$ has more than one root?

Comment: When $f$ has just one root, it is necessarily "rational" over the field of coefficients. If this answer is not clear to you, do not hesitate to ask again.